# Apply Wait on shadow DOM Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dom

How can we apply wait on shadow dom web elements using selenium webdriver?
The normal wait using the following code doesn't seem to work on shadow elements.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/widget-commponent//div/div[2]")))
```

Kindly help if anyone knows how to do that.
Thanks.

Comment: another valid question shot down... those supposed answers show how to access a shadowed element but not how to use an explicit wait on it.

Comment: Here's what I found in Java.  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(shadowRoot.findElement(By.className("example-class-name"))));